# Comment out characters for zf

Tags: folding

I use `foldmethod=marker` in vim with default `{{{` and `}}}` markers and `zf`command to fold/unfold visually selected blocks.

It works fine in most file types, for example:

```
/*{{{*/
console.log("this is a javascript file")
/*}}}*/

<!--{{{-->
<p>This is a HTML file</p>
<!--}}}-->

/*{{{*/
/* This is a css file */
/*}}}*/

#{{{
echo "this is a bash script"
#}}}

Etc...
```

But in SQL files, it uses common `/*` ... `*/` syntax which, at least for PostgreSQL is invalid.

```
//{{{
select 'This is a SQL file'
//}}}
```

I also use [tcomment](https://github.com/vim-scripts/tComment) pluggin to comment in and out things with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> and it works well with SQL files too so I think it should be an issue with `zf` command itself or some configuration parameter which I doesn't know. But I don't know where to look for...

For example:

```
-- select 'This is a commented out query'
```

Any clue or suggestion will be welcomed.

Comment: When in SQL file, what's the value for `foldmethod` and `foldmarker`?

Comment: foldmethod=marker, foldmarker={{{, }}}. But markers are right. What is wrong is the preffix to coment out that marker in valid sql syntax. I mean: when I type `zf`, I get `/*{{{*/ [...] /*}}}*/` instead of `--{{{ [...] --}}}`.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. If you `:set commentstring=--%s` - does it work?

Comment: YES! Thanks. I thought that it should be a problem with folding configuration because, as I said, with tcomment it works, but probably is tcomment plugin which is doing it "wrong" in the sense of it ignorres commentstring.

Comment: ...now I only need to add an autocmd to set it for sql files. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As worked out in comments, solution is to set proper `commentstring`. The default is for `sql` file to `commentstring=/*%s*/`. So in this case you need to:

```
:set commentstring=--%s
```

You can automate it via autocmmand or by modeline:

```
-- vim:set commentstring=--%s:
```

.

```
autocmd FileType sql set commentstring=--%s
```

Comment: Of course! I just did it (thanks to your comments) and worked fine! Thanks.

Comment: As a note, it still doesn't work for syntax blocks ( http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4168 ), but I will not cry for that. I rarely use them and, in this case is easy to temporary change the whole filetype while editing them.