# Change default character for comments

Tags: vimscript, comments

The assigned character for comments is `"` for vimscript. But i want to change it to some other character (like `*` or `#` for example).

Based on [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10564/comment-out-characters-for-zf/10565#10565) post, it seems like the string `setlocal commentstring=\"%s` in the file `vim.vim` (which is usually in `/usr/local/share/vim/vimversion_number_here`) is only to add appropriate comment tags around Vim fold markers (thanks to @BLayer in the comment for pointing this out).

But if possible, i would want to have a *third* character for comment (since `#` work for vimscript9 for comment, though i don't know where it's defined).

How could i do this?

Comment: read my updated post, found a way on how to do it :P @BLayer

Comment: Really? Damn. That's awful surprising. It's not allowed in most languages I'm aware of.

Comment: To answer the other part of your comment above, the same method i found apply for the other filetype (.c, .py, etc) since they have their own comment character assigned, in the `ftplugin` directory, as i described in my post. Thing is, i don't know how to set more than three different character for comment, as the same time (since the `#` char already work + `"` for vimscript) @BLayer

Comment: The docs say this option is only used to add markers for folding. I need to look closer at what this actually is.

Comment: really? the comment above the mentioned string does say `" Comments start with a double quote; in Vim9 script # would also work` and i can always jump in and try to modify the string and see if it work...

Comment: What I've read says this is only to add appropriate comment tags around Vim fold markers....i.e. dynamic and depending on current filetype...when, for instance, you add a fold with `zf`. Example: [Comment out characters for zf](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10565)  I've never encountered this setting before, TBH.

Comment: Interesting...I guess I'll edit my post to reflect this then :) thanks for looking it up! @BLayer

Comment: I only encountered it because i run a grep query on the whole vim directory (the one in `/usr/local/share/vim` etc) and used `comment` as query. (use fzf with cat as preview, it's pretty useful for these things) @BLayer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113144/discussion-between-nordine-lotfi-and-b-layer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're under the impression that the `'commentstring'` option can be used to set which character or format is recognized as a comment in Vimscript... But that's not at all what it is about!

It's about telling Vim which format is recognized as a comment in the current language (as in, the current `filetype`), so that if Vim needs to insert a comment somewhere, it can use this option as a template.

See [`:help 'commentstring'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27commentstring%27):

> A template for a comment. The `%s` in the value is replaced with the comment text. Currently only used to add markers for folding, see [fold-marker](https://vimhelp.org/fold.txt.html#fold-marker).

Even though it looks like Vim itself doesn't make much use of this option, it's also used by plug-ins that manage comments, for example [vim-commentary leverages the option](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary#faq) for its own configuration.

So, in short, same as you can't really change what a comment in C or Python or Java is, you can't really change what a comment in Vimscript is... It's part of the language, it's baked in.